# How to do custom time (semi-monthly and 10-day) splits of calendar year data in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, scipy

I have a range of days starting on January 1 1930 and ending on May 7 2020 in `df`. I want columns that divide the year in different ways: so far I have columns denoting the Year, Month and Week.  I also want columns denoting `Dekad` and `Semi-Month` increments.

Dekad is 10-day period where January 1-10 is dekad "1", Jan 11-20 is dekad "2", etc and the final dekad "37" will have a length less than 10 because 365 does not divide evenly by 10.

For `semi-month`, I want to divide each month in halve and increment over the year. This is a little trickier because months have different lengths, but basically Jan 1-15 would be "1" and Jan 16-31 would be "2" and Feb 1-14 would be "3" and Feb 15-28 would be "4", etc. (in a non leap year.)

In other words, I want custom date time splits or custom periods of the calendar year. This should be relatively easy to do for the dekads, so that is my priority more so than the semi-monthly split.

Is there something baked into the `datetime` package that can already do this or do I need to write custom function(s)?

If the latter, a starting off point for `Dekad` is to maybe take the first_day_of_year object and then add `datetime.timedelta(days=10)` and increment from 1 to 37 for each dekad? Suggestions welcome.

```py
# import packages 
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import *

# create dataframe with dates
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Datetime'] = pd.date_range(start='1/1/1930', periods=33000, freq='D')

# extract the Year, Month, etc. from the Datetime 
df['Year'] = [dt.year for dt in df['Datetime']]
df['Month'] = [dt.month for dt in df['Datetime']]
df['Week'] = [dt.week for dt in df['Datetime']]
```

This is what I eventually want:

```
    Datetime    Year    Month   Week  Semi_Month  Dekad
0   1930-01-01  1930    1       1     1           1
1   1930-01-02  1930    1       1     1           1
2   1930-01-03  1930    1       1     1           1
3   1930-01-04  1930    1       1     1           1
4   1930-01-05  1930    1       1     1           1
... ... ... ... ...
32995   2020-05-03  2020    5   18    9           13
32996   2020-05-04  2020    5   19    9           13
32997   2020-05-05  2020    5   19    9           13
32998   2020-05-06  2020    5   19    9           13
32999   2020-05-07  2020    5   19    9           13
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a dekad 37. By conventional definition, every month has 3 dekads with the last dekad of the month running from day 21 until the end of the month (so having 8, 9, 10 or 11 days). This is basically the same as what you propose for the semi-month. I don't know pandas, but in R you can calculate the dekad with `(m - 1) * 3 + pmin((d - 1) %/% 10 + 1, 3)`, where `m` is the month, `d` is the day, `%/%` is integer division, and the `pmin()` function selects the parallel minimum (so that day 31 becomes 3, not 4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for Dekad, it is actually the [`dayofyear`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.dayofyear.html) integer divided by 10 plus 1. for the Semi_month, the idea is to check where the `day` of the month is greater than (`gt`) than the last day of the month obtained with [`MonthEnd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd.html) divided by 2, add the month number times 2 minus 1.

```
df['Semi_Month'] = (df['Datetime'].dt.day
                      .gt((df['Datetime']+pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd()).dt.day//2) 
                      + df['Month']*2 -1)
df['Dekad'] = df['Datetime'].dt.dayofyear//10+1

print(df)
        Datetime  Year  Month  Week  Semi_Month  Dekad
0     1930-01-01  1930      1     1           1      1
1     1930-01-02  1930      1     1           1      1
2     1930-01-03  1930      1     1           1      1
3     1930-01-04  1930      1     1           1      1
4     1930-01-05  1930      1     1           1      1
...          ...   ...    ...   ...         ...    ...
32995 2020-05-03  2020      5    18           9     13
32996 2020-05-04  2020      5    19           9     13
32997 2020-05-05  2020      5    19           9     13
32998 2020-05-06  2020      5    19           9     13
32999 2020-05-07  2020      5    19           9     13
```

Comment: Thank you! This was an elegant solution. Maybe you can help with a similar, easier problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63609191/what-is-the-datetime-equivalent-for-pandas-dayofyear