# What is the datetime equivalent for pandas dayofyear?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I'm looking to get an array of values of day of year from a list of `datetimes`. I can get the week number, for example, using the method `isocalendar`. But what's the method for an integer day of year? Using pandas this is [dayofyear](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.dayofyear.html), but how do I get this using the `datetime` package?

```py
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import *

datetimes = np.arange(
    datetime(2012,1,1), datetime(2017,1,1), timedelta(days=1)
    ).astype(datetime)

week_value_by_day = np.array([datetime.isocalendar()[1] for datetime in datetimes])
```

At the end of the day, I want an array using this code `np.array([datetime.<something> for datetime in datetimes])` where the `<something>` gives me the integer day of year and results in  `array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6..365])`.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620305/convert-year-month-day-to-day-of-year-in-python) help?

Comment: @anky I don't think so, `np.array([datetime.timetuple().tm_yday for datetime in datetimes])` returns an empty array `array([], dtype=float64)`

Comment: The input in your question - `datetimes ` returns blank

Comment: Sorry for that typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using strftime:

```
np.array([int(i.strftime("%j")) for i in datetimes])
```

However,

```
np.array([datetime.timetuple().tm_yday for datetime in datetimes])
```

works and is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short example of days between dates, using only the Python built-in datetime module:

```
import datetime

dates = [
    datetime.date(2019, 12, 30), datetime.date(2019, 12, 31),
    datetime.date(2020, 1, 1),   datetime.date(2020, 1, 2)
]

for d in dates:
    base_date = d.replace(month=1, day=1)
    days_between = (d - base_date) / datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    print(base_date, d, days_between)

2019-01-01 2019-12-30 363.0
2019-01-01 2019-12-31 364.0
2020-01-01 2020-01-01 0.0
2020-01-01 2020-01-02 1.0
```

You would add 1 to `days_between` if you wanted 1-based indexing (Jan 1 is 'day zero' in this example).

This is based on the section 'Examples of Usage: date' here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html